# Complex column names when importing into PowerPivot from SSAS

Tags: excel, ssas, powerpivot

I am using Excel 2013. I am creating a PowerPivot connection in Excel to an SSAS multidimensional cube. When the query is imported, the column names in PowerPivot are messy. For example, if I am referencing an SSAS member called [File].[File Name].[File Name], my PowerPivot column name is "FileFile NameFile Name", which is the member without the periods.

How do I get the PowerPivot column name to show as simply "File Name"?